# How to achieved collision detection in Translate Transition (in JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, collision-detection, javafx-8

I have written the below JavaFX program in which two rectangle nodes are in translate transition:

```
public class Test extends Application{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");


    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20,20,50, 50);
    rect1.setArcHeight(15);
    rect1.setArcWidth(15);
    rect1.setFill(Color.RED);

    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(20,20,30, 30);
    rect2.setArcHeight(15);
    rect2.setArcWidth(15);
    rect2.setFill(Color.RED);

    TranslateTransition translateTransition1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), rect1);
    translateTransition1.setFromX(0);
    translateTransition1.setToX(300);
    translateTransition1.setToY(300);
    translateTransition1.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    translateTransition1.setAutoReverse(true);
    translateTransition1.play();

   TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), rect2);
   translateTransition2.setFromX(300);
   translateTransition2.setToX(0);
   translateTransition2.setToY(300);
   translateTransition2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
   translateTransition2.setAutoReverse(true);
   translateTransition2.play();


    borderPane.getChildren().add(rect1);
    borderPane.getChildren().add(rect2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.show();

  }

}
```

How can I implement collision detection of the two rectangle nodes which are in Translate Transition?

Comment: As a side note, you should accept answer to some of your previously asked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With rectangles it's pretty easy; just get their bounds in the parent and see if they intersect. The only drawback with this is it doesn't take into account the curved corners: you may need to compute that by hand if you want that level of accuracy. For non-rectangular shapes you can also just observe the bounds in parent properties, but you'd need to do the computation by hand to see if the shapes intersect.

```
    ObservableBooleanValue colliding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(new Callable<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return rect1.getBoundsInParent().intersects(rect2.getBoundsInParent());
        }

    }, rect1.boundsInParentProperty(), rect2.boundsInParentProperty());

    colliding.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs,
                Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                System.out.println("Colliding");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not colliding");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James, it works perfectly. I just need 1 more suggestion from your side regarding the use of the translate translation (with the logic you provided above) and using Timeline frames (with the logic of Shape intersection). Which approach will be efficient?

Answer (score 4):

`TranslateTransition` isn't meant to support Collision Detection. It simply moves A to B without any regards to the state of anything but its node.

You would need a `Transition` mechanism that is aware of the other objects on the board.

The good news is that creating a `Transition` isn't too hard. You can create a class that inherits [Transition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html) and simply implement the `interpolate()` method.

[From the JavaDoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html)

> Below is a simple example. It creates a small animation that updates
>   the text property of a Text node. It starts with an empty String and
>   adds gradually letter by letter until the full String was set when the
>   animation finishes.

```
 final String content = "Lorem ipsum";
 final Text text = new Text(10, 20, "");

 final Animation animation = new Transition() {
     {
         setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
     }

     protected void interpolate(double frac) {
         final int length = content.length();
         final int n = Math.round(length * (float) frac);
         text.setText(content.substring(0, n));
     }

 };
```

The bad news is that having a successful collision detection mechanism is a bit harder. I'm really no expert on the subject, but I would probably have a `ObservableList` of `Nodes` that have collision, pass it to the `Transition` and on the `interpolate` method I would do a intersection check of the node that's moving against all the other `nodes` and leave it still if he cannot move.

If you want anything better than that, you'll probably want to look into a 2D Game Framework like Slick2D.

Comment: Hi Peekay, Thanks for your response and also thanks for the suggestion of creating new custom Transition.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Made a few simple alterations and went with a State based approach, code has been updated.

Well my approach is different that all the above ...

NOTE: I'm using 1.8 source

I created a Collidable interface:

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

public interface Collidable{
    public enum CollisionState{
        WAITING,
        TOUCHING;        
    }

    ObjectProperty<CollisionState> state = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(CollisionState.WAITING);
    public default ReadOnlyObjectProperty<CollisionState> collisionStateProperty(){return state;}
    public default CollisionState getCollisionState(){return state.get();}

    BooleanProperty collided = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false){{
            addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable1, Boolean oldValue, Boolean touching) -> {
                if(touching){
                    state.set(CollisionState.TOUCHING);
                }else{
                    state.set(CollisionState.WAITING);
                }
            });
    }};
    public default boolean hasCollided(){return collided.get();}
    public default BooleanProperty collidedProperty(){return collided;}

    public default void checkCollision(Shape src, Shape other){
        if(Shape.intersect(src, other).getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > -1 && !getCollisionState().equals(CollisionState.TOUCHING)){
            collided.set(true); 
            handleCollision(other);
        }else if(Shape.intersect(src, other).getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() <= 0){
            collided.set(false);            
        }
    }

    public void handleCollision(Shape other);

}
```

And a simple implementation:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Dub-Laptop
 */
public class CollisionTesting extends Application {

    private TranslateTransition cAnim;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Collision Testing");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100,50, Color.AQUA);
        r.setLayoutX(10);
        r.setLayoutY(200);

        CollidableCircle c = new CollidableCircle(50, Color.GREEN);
        c.setLayoutX(800);
        c.setLayoutY(200);

        /* can change this to anything you like 
           I used translateXProperty for simplicity
        */                                  
        c.translateXProperty().addListener((Observable observable) -> {
            c.checkCollision(c, r);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(r, c);

        TranslateTransition rAnim = new TranslateTransition();

        rAnim.setToX(600);
        rAnim.setAutoReverse(true);
        rAnim.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        rAnim.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
        rAnim.setNode(r);

        cAnim = new TranslateTransition();

        cAnim.setToX(-590);
        cAnim.setAutoReverse(true);
        cAnim.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        cAnim.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
        cAnim.setNode(c);

        rAnim.play();
        cAnim.play();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class CollidableCircle extends Circle implements Collidable{

        public CollidableCircle(double radius, Paint fill) {
            super(radius, fill);
            new AnimationTimer(){
                @Override
                public void handle(long now) {
                    root.getChildren().filtered((Node n)->{
                        return !n.equals(CollidableCircle.this) && n instanceof Shape;
                    }).forEach(other ->{
                        checkCollision(CollidableCircle.this, (Shape)other);
                    });
                }
            }.start();
            // I added this for local property changes to this node
            collisionStateProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends CollisionState> observable, CollisionState oldValue, CollisionState newValue) -> {
                if(newValue.equals(CollisionState.TOUCHING)){  
                    setScaleX(1.25);
                    setScaleY(1.25);
                    setFill(Color.GREENYELLOW);
                    cAnim.pause();
                }else if(newValue.equals(CollisionState.WAITING)){      
                    setScaleX(1.0);
                    setScaleY(1.0);
                    setFill(Color.GREEN);
                    cAnim.play();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void handleCollision(Shape other) {            
           // handle updates that affect other node here
           System.out.println("Collided with : " + other.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

    }    

}
```

IMHO rather than using Bounds for checking Shape collisions, use the boolean :

(Shape.intersect(s1,s2).getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > -1)

This approach is more accurate for Shapes as it will check for non-null pixels within the Shape Bounds, rather than the normal rectangular Bounds.

Though if you really want to use Bounds, this should work also:

```
if(sourceShape.getBoundsInLocal().intersects(otherShape.getBoundsInParent()){
    Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(sourceShape, otherShape);
    if(intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth > -1){
        // handle code here
    }
}
```

though, as you can see it's more verbose and virtually the same as my other method.

Hope this helps.